# How to put two conditionals in :class VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I'm creating a sidebar with a lot of features soo I need add two conditionals in my :class, but i don't know how to do this. That's what I do:

```
:class=" showSidebar ? 'open' : 'closed', showSidebarMini ? 'openmini' : 'closedmini'"
```

Comment: i think you forgot the curly braces class="{conditionals}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use array of classes:

```
:class="[(showSidebar ? 'open' : 'closed'), (showSidebarMini ? 'openmini' : 'closedmini')]"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do in object style:

Example:

```json
{
  'open': showSidebar,
  'closed': !showSidebar,
  'openmini': showSidebarMini,
  'closedmini': !showSidebarMini
}
```

In your case:

```css
:class="{ 'open': showSidebar, 'closed': !showSidebar, 'openmini': showSidebarMini, 'closedmini': !showSidebarMini }"
```

Answer (score 3):

you must use object syntax when you have a condition in class

```
v-bind:class="{'open' : showSidebar , 'openmini' : showSidebarMini}"
```

and use array in your class when you need toggle class

```
v-bind:class="[showSidebar ? 'open' : 'closed', showSidebarMini ? 'openmini' : 'closedmini']"
```